# Can I use REST API if the site is protected with .htpasswd

Tags: rest-api

is there a way to use Wordpress REST API if the site is protected with **AuthType Basic** using **htpasswd**?

Comment: Before anyone answers I think they may want to know why you need to do this. There are different and easier ways to manage and authenticate. Please be as descriptive with your question as possible. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to supply basic auth headers like below :

```
curl -D- \
   -X GET \
   -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxyyyzzz" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   "https://your-domain.com/rest/api/v1"
```

*"xxxxyyyzzz" is the username:password base64 encoded*